# how to disable mouseout visibility="hidden" effect for medias smaller than 768px?

Tags: javascript, media-queries, visibility, mouseout

I am pretty new at Javascript. I created this effect where text appears under an image icon when the user hovers over it. I would like the effect to only work when the screen is over 768px and for the text to just stay visible at all times when viewed on smaller devices. I've tried using different variants of

```
 if (screen.width < 768px) {}  
 and  
 @media all and (min-width: 768px) {} else {}
```

to control the effect to my liking but without any luck. Help??? 
Here is my code:

```
<section id="s1">
<h1><a href="web/services.html">
     <img src="images/ICON-TRANSCRIPTION.png" class="hover"></a></h1>
<p class="text">TRANSCRIPTION</p>
</section>

<script> 
$('.hover').mouseover(function() {
$('.text').css("visibility","visible");
}); 

$('.hover').mouseout(function() {
$('.text').css("visibility","hidden");}); 

</script>
```

Comment: Use CSS :hover to do your CSS changes, and then use media queries to do it for your specified viewport. You don't need any JS for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you must do it via JS(this can be accomplished with [CSS media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries)), first you should get the width of the window and set it as a variable, then you can set up your conditional statement like so:

```
function mouseVisibility() {
    var w = $(window).width();
    if (w > 767) {
        $('.hover').mouseover(function() {
            $('.text').css("visibility","visible");
        }); 

        $('.hover').mouseout(function() {
        $('.text').css("visibility","hidden");}); 
    }
}
mouseVisibility();
```

Additionally, you should fire the function again if the user resizes the browser window:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    mouseVisibility();
});
```

Comment: You're welcome, although I must stress that using the media query solution provided by @MatthewDarnell would be the much more elegant solution.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need any JS to do this. The easiest way to accomplish this is to define the media query to be what you desire, set the element to `visibility: hidden;` and then add a hover rule to change the visibility attribute.

The visibility would be visible by default (on smaller screens), then set to hidden by the media query with the added hover functionality for larger screens.

```
@media all and (min-width: 768px) {
    .hover { visibility: hidden; }
    .hover:hover { visibility: visible; }
}
```

Comment: thank you- but i think this would affect the visibility of the icon: .hover but not the .text distinctively?

Comment: Without going into too much detail, if you really need to use JS, you should be adding classes, which can then be targeted by the CSS. So you would make a hover rule in the JS that added a class to the text element, and then base your CSS off of that class that gets added.